# std::function argument binding

Tags: c++, function, binding

Can someone explain me why some of these implementation works while other doesn't and what's happening under the hood? Is there some performance issue for example with f1?

What should I google for finding these mapping rules?

```cpp
#include<string> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> 

bool f1(const std::string& str1)  //works
{
    std::cout<<"f1"<<str1<<std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool f2(std::string& str1) //not working
{
    std::cout<<"f2"<<str1<<std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool f3(std::string str1) //works
{
    std::cout<<"f3"<<str1<<std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool f4(std::string* str1)
{
    std::cout<<"f4"<<str1<<std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main(){
    std::function<bool(std::string)> fp=&f1;
    std::string x="Hello world";
    fp(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which of the multiple things wrong here are you struggling with? I suspect it's `"Hello world"` not being a `std::string` (it is a [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), a dumb old null-terminated array of `char`), thus requiring conversion and a temporary variable to store the converted value, and not being able to take references and pointers to temporaries because of their extremely short lifespans.

Comment: Recommendation: If my suspicion is correct, remove the `std::function` from the equation to focus on the problem better. If you're having problems with the `std::function`, you'll want to focus on it instead.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: Removed tmp object created.
My question is why some of these functions can be binded to fp  while other can't?

Answer (score 2):

As explained on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), you can assign a function `f` to a `std::function<R(Args...)>` if `f` is [callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) for argument types `Args...` and return type `R`.

In your example, `f1` and `f3` work because you can call either of them with a `std::string` rvalue. You can't call `f2` or `f4` with a `std::string` rvalue.

Comment: It's not clear to me why I can't call f2 that receives a `std::string&` passing a `std::string`

Comment: @Francesco.S Non-const references don't bind to rvalues. I'm not sure why it has to be an rvalue, but it's in the definition of callable: `INVOKE<R>(f, std::declval<ArgTypes>()...)` must be well-formed and the `std::declval` part makes rvalues.